# How can I edit an existing PHP file using Hooks?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm new to PHP, and I have to edit an existing PHP code for a WordPress plugin to fit my needs.

What I know about hooks is that we can append an extra function inside a function.

But right now I need to edit an entire PHP file, add an extra line of code in the middle of the page.

The problem I'm facing is that the code is not a set of functions for me to use hooks but instead it's like this:

```
<?php
global $current_user;

master_user_content_block_start(array(
    'title' => esc_html__('My Profile', 'master'),
    'title-link-text' => esc_html__('Edit Profile', 'master'),
    'title-link' => master_get_template_url('user', array('page_type'=>'edit-profile'))
));

$profile_list = array(
    'full_name' => esc_html__('Name', 'master'),
    'gender' => esc_html__('Gender', 'master'),
    'birth_date' => esc_html__('Birth Date', 'master'),
    'country' => esc_html__('Country', 'master'),
    'email' => esc_html__('Email', 'master'),
    'phone' => esc_html__('Phone', 'master'),
    'contact_address' => esc_html__('Contact Address', 'master'),
);
echo '<div class="master-my-profile-wrapper" >';
echo '<div class="master-my-profile-avatar" >';
$avatar = get_the_author_meta('master-user-avatar', $current_user->data->ID);
if( !empty($avatar['thumbnail']) ){
    echo '<img src="' . esc_url($avatar['thumbnail']) . '" alt="profile-image" />';
}else if( !empty($avatar['file_url']) ){
    echo '<img src="' . esc_url($avatar['file_url']) . '" alt="profile-image" />';
}else{
    echo get_avatar($current_user->data->ID, 85);
}
echo '</div>';

$even_column = true;
echo '<div class="master-my-profile-info-wrap clearfix" >';
foreach( $profile_list as $meta_field => $field_title ){
    $extra_class  = 'master-my-profile-info-' . $meta_field;
    $extra_class .= ($even_column)? ' master-even': ' master-odd';
    

    echo '<div class="master-my-profile-info ' . esc_attr($extra_class) . ' clearfix" >';
    echo '<span class="master-head" >' . $field_title . '</span>';
    echo '<span class="master-tail" >';
    if( $meta_field == 'birth_date' ){
        $user_meta = master_get_user_meta($current_user->data->ID, $meta_field, '-');
        if( $user_meta == '-' ){
            echo $user_meta;
        }else{
            echo master_date_format($user_meta);
        }
    }else if( $meta_field == 'gender' ){
        $user_meta = master_get_user_meta($current_user->data->ID, $meta_field, '-');
        if( $user_meta == 'male' ){
            echo esc_html__('Male', 'master');
        }else if( $user_meta == 'female' ){
            echo esc_html__('Female', 'master');
        }
    }else{
        echo master_get_user_meta($current_user->data->ID, $meta_field, '-');
    }

    echo '</span>';
    echo '</div>';

    $even_column = !$even_column;
}
echo '</div>';
```

How can I edit the code of this page without changing the main file content using an additional php file to avoide having problems when the plug-in update.

Example of the edit I want to remove the birth date field and change the word Male to adult and Female to child.

Comment: Depending on the license of the plugin - have you considered copying the contents into a custom plugin - making the changes and then just using your own plugin? This way, you are in control of future updates, and you can modify the code directly.

Comment: In the very, very specific case of changing text, you can hook into the [`translate`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate/) function, probably at the `gettext` hook, and look for your input keywords along with the `$domain` of `master`, however that will be a global change which may or may not do what you want it to do, and I would only recommend doing that if it is your last option. A better option might be to find what is calling this code, write your own version, and get the system to use your new code instead.